# TCP/IP rx data drop

Tags: linux, networking, buffer

I have an intermittent problem with receiving data over TCP/IP from a (Windows) server. The data is sent at 160Mbit/s and client application is running on a 64-bit Suse Linux Enterprise server. I am monitoring using the sar program. http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/sar1.html

At some random point I receive rx drops and I can also see in ifconfig that the error counter has increased.

The text below comes from the link above.

"**rxdrop/s**
Number of received packets dropped per second because  of
a lack of space in linux buffers."

The documentation refers to a lack of space in the Linux buffers. Which buffer is this and how can I increase this buffer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this site will give an answer to my question.
https://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~sparkst/howto/network_tuning.php

and this one:
http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2005/11/17/tcp_tuning.html

Comment: Both links are defunct now.